# Android Home screen animation using widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-animation, android-wallpaper, daydream

I am trying to create an Android app where there will be simple animations on the phone at all times.
The app will be similar to "Crack Your Screen Prank"
or
Facebook Messenger,
where it will be on top of the home screen, but animated.

At first I thought this was widget but I am not sure anymore.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in three ways:

- [A Widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)
- [A Live Wallpaper](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/02/live-wallpapers.html)
- [A Daydream](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/12/daydream-interactive-screen-savers.html)

Its even possible to create an app that has all three of these features and offers the user the option of using one or more of them simultaneously.

Comment: I don't think I want a wallpaper since I need animated icon to have user iteraction. (click and go to my app).
Is Facebook Messenger using A Widget?

Comment: yes probably ... and on click of the widget it goes to the app

Comment: I have been going through the widget code for a bit but can't seem to find. Is there a sample code that lets me drag widget around the screen like facebook messenger?

Comment: any widget can be dragged and placed anywhere on the home screen